# Correct way to catch SIGINT and cleanup?

Tags: crystal-lang

Writing a cli tool that on startup turns on the OS X web proxy and on shutdown I'd like to turn it off again. What's the correct way to catch SIGINT and perform app cleanup? Tried the following and it traces the message but does not run the system command or exit:

```
Signal::INT.trap do
  puts "trap"
  fork do
    system "networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi off"
  end
  exit
end
```

This code does exit but gives an 'Invalid memory access' error

```
at_exit do
  fork do
    system "networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi off"
  end
end

LibC.signal Signal::INT.value, ->(s : Int32) { exit }
```

```
Invalid memory access (signal 10) at address 0x10d3a8e00
[0x10d029b4b] *CallStack::print_backtrace:Int32 +107
[0x10d0100d5] __crystal_sigfault_handler +181
[0x7fff6c5b3b3d] _sigtramp +29
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the complete 'app' using `Signal::INT.trap`, for me running that will correctly turn on and off the OS X proxy settings but the loop will continue to run after the interrupt signal.

```
fork do
  system "networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi  127.0.0.1 4242"
end

Signal::INT.trap do
  puts "trap"
  fork do
    system "networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi off"
  end
  exit
end

loop do
  sleep 1
  puts "foo"
end
```

Comment: `Signal::INT.trap` works as expected in my test code snippet.  Could you create a MCVE to demonstrate the problem? It's probably just `networksetup` not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [Fibers](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/guides/concurrency.html#fibers)?

```
spawn do
  system "networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi  127.0.0.1 4242"
end

sleep 0.1

Signal::INT.trap do
  puts "trap"
  spawn do
    system "networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi off"
  end
  sleep 0.1
  exit
end

loop do
  sleep 1
  puts "foo"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the trouble is from crystal-lang's `fork`, which has some strange semantic meaning.

When you tried to start a working process to run `system` call, crystal duplicated the `loop` too...

And when `exit` is executed, the first loop exited, not the forked one.

To verify this, you can write some `sleep` into the `fork` and `INT.trap` block like this:

```
fork do
  system "echo \"start\""
end

Signal::INT.trap do
  puts "trap"
  fork do
    system "echo \"off\""
    sleep 15
  end
  sleep 20
  exit
end

loop do
  sleep 1
  puts "foo"
end
```

Then try to watch the result of `ps` command continuously.

Alternative approach has been answered by @Sergey Fedorov, using fiber.

Further reading: [Process.fork has dangerous semantics](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/6421)